# Can I limit number of new lines in multiline asp:TextBox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Can I limit into only 3 new lines in multiline asp:TextBox using javascript or C#

Answer (score -1, accepted):

only by setting Rows property to 3 you can achieve this like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server" Rows="3" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

use javascript:

```
function validate(e, max,maxchar)
{
var text = e.value.replace(/\s+$/g,""); var split = text.split("\n");
if (split.length <= max && text.length <=maxchar)
{
  return true;
}
else if (split.length >= max || e.value.length >=maxchar)
{
 return false;
}
}
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" onkeypress="return validate(this,max_number,maxchar_number)"/>
```

change the value of `max_number` and `maxchar_number` based on your requirement.

Comment: Thank  you. When I press enter key it takes one space from maxchar_number, can I avoid it.